# How to do I migrate from v10 to V11 on PostgreSQL using pg_upgrade on Windows?

Tags: windows, postgresql, command-line-interface

I need some help on migrating from v10 to V11 on PostgreSQL using pg_upgrade on Windows machine?

I am new to using PostgreSQL, and looking at the [documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/11/pgupgrade.html), it is not helpful on using `pg_upgrade`on Windows CLI.

Note: this a local machine, I am looking to perform the migration on.

Comment: There is even a complete sample command line to use under `9. Run pg_upgrade`

Comment: You should be more specific where exactly your problem is.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name, I followed the steps on ```9. Run pg_upgrade```and got the following error ```could not open version file pg_version```

Comment: Did you run `initdb` for the target data directory?